# qt QAbstractItemModel drag&drop for moving items performs remove/insert

Tags: c++, qt

I created a class derived from `QAbrstractItemModel` to be displayed under a `QTreeView`. I need drag&drop operations to reorder items with the mouse.

However, I noticed that when I do this, the items are moved by removing the indices and then creating new ones under the new position. But I reimplemented the `moveRows()` method.

What can be wrong? Or is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `moveRows` (and all its companion functions) has been introduced in Qt 5. Drag and drop support for QAbstractItemModel subclasses comes from Qt 4, and even in Qt 5 it unfortunately still consists of a insert + a remove, because we don't want to break Qt 4 projects when they get ported to Qt 5.

Hence, Qt 5 doesn't make any use of `moveRows` (e.g. see [here](https://code.woboq.org/data/symbol.html?root=../qt5/&ref=_ZN18QAbstractItemModel8moveRowsERK11QModelIndexiiS2_i#uses)).

Long term, Qt will need to find a way to make use of the move operations on models, necessarily as an opt-in feature (we can't break code!). The question is really "who will do this huge job"...

Comment: The remove + insert is not working correctly for me. When I move an item or append it to a child, I see that my `removeRows` is called, but not my `insertRows`. As a result, when I move some item, it always appears at the end of my tree. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I think `dropMimeData` should get called, not `insertRows`, followed by a `removeRows`. Cf. [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView9dropEventEP10QDropEvent) and the documentation here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-model-view-classes . When in doubt, I typically look at the source.